# how to calculate accuracy in segmentation model?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, bounding-box

I evaluate a segmentation model using a bound box technique. Then I
sum the values of TP, FP, TN, and FN for each image. The total images were
10 (rows numbers in the below table). I need to calculate the accuracy of this model.
The equation of **accuracy = (TP+TN)/(TP+FP+FN+TN)**

(*TP+FP+FN+TN*) is the total number. I **confused** of the total here ...(**actual** and **predicted**

**The question** is: what is the value of the Total Number in this case? Why?

```
imgNo TP    FP  TN  FN
   1    4   0   0   0
   2    6   1   1   0
   3    2   3   0   0
   4    1   1   1   0
   5    5   0   0   0
   6    3   1   0   0
   7    0   3   1   0
   8    1   0   0   0
   9    3   2   1   0
  10    4   1   1   0
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TP :** True Positive is the number of objects you correctly identified in image.

**FP :** False Positive are objects you identified but actually that's a mistake because there is no such object in ground-truth.

**TN :** True Negative is when algorithm doesn't identify any object and indeed that is the case with ground-truth. i.e. correct negative identification.

**FN :** False Negative is when your algorithm failed to identify objects (i.e. the ground truth contains objects in the image(s), but it is marked as background by your algorithm). In other words, you missed identifying an object.
Its 0 anyway in your experiments.

So, TP+TN = True Total cases. Don't include FN because that is wrong detection.

Comment: What about total is it total for predicted data or for ground truth data. I get two different numbers of summation. Can you help me? I confused

Comment: Total (TP+FP+FN+TN) is used to count all 4 types of possibilities. Just a mathematical way. There are many more ways - depends on your need. Refer to Receiver operating characteristic on wikipedia to get more ideas - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic

Comment: Yes, it is a mathematical way and I already get it. But I require , I have two total are not equal to each other. The first one is the total of segmented part in the ground truth (2,652 rows).  The second one is the total of segmented algorithm in the predicated result (2,629 rows). Is it a normal in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by "total of segmented part" ? Is it sum over some column? Or anything else?
The number of rows in algorithm-segmentation can be less than ground-truth-segmentation when algorithm fails to detect all.

Comment: I mean total number when i sum up the ground truth bound box segmentation.

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand "sum up the ground truth bound box segmentation". How can we do that ?

Comment: If I have 3 images. The ground truth of the first image has 3 boxes. The second image has 2 boxes. The third image has 4 boxes. The all boxes are 3+2+4=9 boxes for all images. The 9 is the total and sum up of bound box segmentation in the ground truth or standard segmentation.

Comment: Okay, so its a sum of column you are talking about. The number of rows in algorithm-segmentation can be less than ground-truth-segmentation when algorithm fails to detect all. Out of total 2652 bounding boxes, algorithm could only find 2629 boxes and failed for (2652-2629)=22 boxes.

Comment: Yes exactly. But, these boxes (22 boxes) must included in FN classes, Aren't they?

Comment: Yes that's correct, Precision (also called "accuracy" sometimes) = Out of the total predictions, how many are correct. Recall = Out of total correct total cases, how many could be correctly identified. The denominator for precision is TP+FP while for Recall is TP + FN

Comment: The TN and FN descriptions in the answer are mixed up. 
False Negatives are the objects that you failed to identify (i.e., the ground truth contains at an object at a location, but it is marked as background).

Answer (score 1):

you can use a heat map to visual analyze your coefficients from a logistic regression.   roc_curve returns the false positives and true positive values.  The confusion matrix returns fp, tp, fn, and fp aggregates.

```
fpr, tpr, threshholds = roc_curve(y_test,y_preds_proba_lr_df)

plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
plt.plot(fpr, tpr)
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('ROC Curve')
plt.show()

 accuracy=round(pipeline['lr'].score(X_train, y_train) * 100, 2)

 print("Model Accuracy={accuracy}".format(accuracy=accuracy))

 cm=confusion_matrix(y_test,predictions)

 sns.heatmap(cm,annot=True,fmt="g")
```